# How do I run a method only when app is opened - xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am fairly new to xcode so please excuse my lack of knowledge.  I am trying to run a method only when the launch image is shown (or on app startup).  It gets images from a website, but I only need it to do that when the app is opened.  I cannot find any help online how to do that.  Thanks for any help in advance!

**Edit:**

I have this in AppDelegate.m

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    Home *home=[[Home alloc] init];
    [home getSlideshow];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

and this in my Home.m

-(void)getSlideshow{

```
[self populateStringArray];
NSString *prefix = @"http://newsongbismarck.com/images/announcements/";
NSString *suffix = @".jpg";

//NSUInteger count = [imageStringArray count];
//get this from the website for now
int number = (int)[imageStringArray count];
int PageCount = number;

//Setup scroll view
UIScrollView *Scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 265, 320, 200)];
Scroller.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
Scroller.pagingEnabled = YES;
Scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(PageCount * Scroller.bounds.size.width, Scroller.bounds.size.height);

//Setup Each View Size
CGRect ViewSize = Scroller.bounds;

int x = PageCount;
int numb = 0;

UIImageView *ImgArray[PageCount];


while(x!=0){
    ImgArray[numb] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:ViewSize];
    [ImgArray[numb] setImage:[self getSlideshowImages:[[prefix stringByAppendingString:imageStringArray[numb]]stringByAppendingString:suffix]]];
    [Scroller addSubview:ImgArray[numb]];

    //Offset View Size
    ViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);

    x--;
    numb++;
}

    CGRect newViewSize = Scroller.bounds;
int NumberOfImages = 21;
int i;
for(i=0;i<NumberOfImages;i++){

    if(i == 0){
        //Setup first picture
        UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newViewSize];
        NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%d.png", i];
        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FilePath]];
        [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
    }else{
        //Setup the rest of the pictures
        newViewSize = CGRectOffset(ViewSize, Scroller.bounds.size.width, 0);
        UIImageView *ImgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:newViewSize];
        NSString *FilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Page_%d.png", i];
        [ImgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:FilePath]];
        [Scroller addSubview:ImgView];
    }
}

    [self.view addSubview:Scroller];
}
```

Comment: Why do you want that fired on app launch instead of the viewWillAppear?

Comment: Because I don't want it to keep having to run it every time I come back to this view. But i'm not sure thats possible.

Comment: Look up persistence and user defaults

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would suggest that you read the section ["Review the source code"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/FirstTutorial.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH3-SW5) from Apple's "Start developing iOS apps today". It explains what happens when your app starts up.

Second, you have 2 scenarios (both methods are in the `AppDelegate` class):

1.Your app is not running and it's being launched. Method called:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

2.Your app is running in the background and it's being opened. Method called:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

You can read more about the `AppDelegate` methods and the app state changes [in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillEnterForeground:).

Answer (score 2):

not sure what exactly you need... I understand you are looking for a function fired on the app start. So there is this function on the AppDelegate class, is the very first invoked function for the iOS delegate.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{}
```

Comment: The method that I want to run is in a UIViewController and it effects the UI.

Comment: Yep, and there are a bunch of other methods in that protocol that can get control for other "state transitions" of the app.

Comment: @LeviBarker -- Where do you think the first view controller gets kicked off?